# Compare multiple cells inside the same column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried the IF and COUNTIF combination, as well as MATCH EXACT (ctrl+shift+enter) function. both do not serve my need.

```
=AND(EXACT(G27:G27,G100))
```

what I have is a column that has various numbers, if nonblank cells contain the same value, return with the same cell value. else, it should return with "Mixed".

The thing is if I made G1 the compared cell, and there's a mix underneath G1, it won't show up.

I want it to compare all nonblank cells. Any advice?
The below result should be "Mixed" based on the fact that 81 is not equal to 82 and 82 is not equal to 83, etc.

but if there's only 5 values that equal "81" from 100 cell range (which means there's 95 blank cells), it should return with value of "81".

and if it's "81" for the first 4 cells but the fifth cell is "82", it should return to "Mixed" as well.

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to show what it is you'r trying.

Comment: Added dear @JvdV

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you could just do a counta and a count if with an If statement. I.e. if(counta(range)=countif(range,criteria),criteria, "mixed")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it help to look at the standard deviation from the whole population? From what I understand you have column G:G with either empty cells **or** numbers. Therefor try:

[image]

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=IF(STDEV.P(G:G),"Mixed",MIN(G:G))
```

If all cells are empty this will return an error. If that's a possibility you could wrap an `IFERROR()`.

Comment: One more question, what if I want to do something like this:

If contains "Value 1, Value 2, Value 3", returns with "x". else if contains "value 1, 2, 3, and 4", returns with "y"; is it possible to specify specific strings to search for within a cell range and return to each condition? @JvdV

Comment: @ahmedel-shamy. Please, new questions get new posts. If this has answered your initial question then consider to accept it and click the checkmark.

Comment: my apologies, done dear. and sorry if I bothered you. have a nice day!